# OpenSUSE 11 AD auth works, but not netbios

Tags: linux, active-directory, netbios, winbind

I've setup a desktop machine with OpenSUSE 11.4 and have Active Directory authentication working properly. I can ping, rdp and ssh to'/from other machines. I can access windows shares from OpenSUSE and samba shares from Windows. However, the hostname won't resolve from any machine on the domain. I can ping other machines on the LAN from OpenSUSE using hostnames, but from the other machines I can only use the IP of the new machine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your host with the DNS system - either from updates by the DHCP server or by manually entering the correct A and PTR entries so that other domain members can resolve.

NetBIOS name resolution is (hopefully) not used anymore as it is everything that the gods have forbidden.

Comment: Take a look at this post. It has good information about a netbios "free" network: http://serverfault.com/questions/119253/netbios-free-network

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solution I found realy simple but it is in dhcp server.

The problem is windows server does not use dhcp server to maintain dns records by default, and uses it's own way. You need to setup account for dhcp server in AD, like dhcp4dns, and include it in group DNS Update Proxy, then in DHCP server in properties setup account for DHCP to interact with DNS, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed NetBios in the firewall?

You can update this in two ways:

- In the Administrator Settings (YaST), look for **Firewall** (probably under **Security and Users**). Run this, and select the **Allowed Services** item. Under the **Service to Allow**, select **Netbios server**, and add it to the list.
- In the Administrator Settings (YaST), look for **Samba Server** (probably under **Network Services**). Run this, and in the **Start-Up** tab, select the **Open Port in Firewall** option.